# CEFSharp RegisterExtension not working

Tags: javascript, c#, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I had an screen scraper app that used CEFSharp that was working fine until I updated CEFSharp to the latest version.  It appears that the way I was registering javascript extension functions no longer works.  Here is my startup code:

```
[STAThread]
public static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();

        settings.RegisterExtension(new CefExtension("showModalDialog", Resources.showModalDialog));

        //Perform dependency check to make sure all relevant resources are in our output directory.
        Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: true, browserProcessHandler: null);

        ProcessCommandLine();

        var browser = new BrowserForm("https://www.google.com");

        Application.Run(browser);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

If I comment out the settings.RegisterExtension line, it runs fine.  It used to work.  Here is the code for my extension:

```
(function () {
    absolutePath = function (href) {
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = href;
        return (link.protocol + "//" + link.host + link.pathname + link.search + link.hash);
    }
    showModalDialog = function (url, arg, opt) {
        url = url || ''; //URL of a dialog
        arg = arg || null; //arguments to a dialog
        opt = opt || 'dialogWidth:300px;dialogHeight:200px'; //options: dialogTop;dialogLeft;dialogWidth;dialogHeight or CSS styles
        var caller = showModalDialog.caller.toString();
        var dialog = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('dialog'));
        dialog.setAttribute('style', opt.replace(/dialog/gi, ''));
        dialog.innerHTML = '<a href="#" id="dialog-close" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 4px; font-size: 20px; color: #000; text-decoration: none; outline: none;">&times;</a><iframe id="dialog-body" name="dialog-body" src="' + absolutePath(url) + '" style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>';
        //document.getElementById('dialog-body').contentWindow.dialogArguments = arg;
        document.getElementById('dialog-close').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            dialog.close();
        });
        document.getElementById('dialog-body').addEventListener('load',     function (e) {
            this.style.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
            this.style.width = this.contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth + 'px';
            this.contentWindow.close = function () {
                dialog.close();
            };
            this.contentWindow.dialogArguments = arg;
            this.window = this.contentWindow;
        });

        dialog.showModal();
        //if using yield
        if (caller.indexOf('yield') >= 0) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                dialog.addEventListener('close', function () {
                    var returnValue = document.getElementById('dialog-    body').contentWindow.returnValue;
                    document.body.removeChild(dialog);
                    resolve(returnValue);
                });
            });
        }
        //if using eval
        var isNext = false;
        var nextStmts = caller.split('\n').filter(function (stmt) {
            if (isNext || stmt.indexOf('showModalDialog(') >= 0)
                return isNext = true;
            return false;
        });

        dialog.addEventListener('close', function () {
            var returnValue = document.getElementById('dialog-body').contentWindow.returnValue;
            document.body.removeChild(dialog);
            //nextStmts[0] = nextStmts[0].replace(/(window\.)?showModalDialog\(.*\)/g, JSON.stringify(returnValue));
            //eval('{\n' + nextStmts.join('\n'));
        });
        throw 'Execution stopped until showModalDialog is closed';
    };
})();
```

Did something change about the syntax of extensions?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: What versions? You will need to log a bug with the CEF project. As a workaround, define an object, and use that object to define your functions.

Comment: I can register a bug report.  I will put the version information there.  I am not a java expert, but it seems that if I put the function in an object, I will have to qualify the function call with the object name.  Even though the ShowModalDialog is obsolete, the web site I am scraping uses it and the web page calls it as a native function, so unless you know a neat trick, I need the function to be available "natively".

Comment: You can execute JavaScript in OnContextCreated to inject your code. See general usage guide for more information.

Comment: I have captured the OnContextCreated event, but CEFRegisterExtension Doesn't seem to be implemented.  I have a resource .js file with my script in it.  Can you tell me which command to use to inject it into the page?  Sorry to be so dense, but I don't do javascript much and I only know enough to get this working then I won't touch it until it breaks again.  Usually years...

Comment: Read the general usage guide on how to execute JavaScript

Comment: I tried frame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync and frame.EvaluateScriptAsync on the resource which appears to show up as a string if you access it with Resources.showModalDialog.  When the page got to the point where it was looking for the function showModalDialog, it didn't exist.  My original implementation worked when I reverted to CEFSharp 49.0.0.  I am just going to roll with that for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=665391

It's a Chrome thing and it doesn't look like they are going to fix it.